# Multiple-View Geometry

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, multiview, projective-geometry

I've two images captured from two cameras of same make placed some distance apart, capturing the same scene. I want to calculate the real world rotation and translation among the two cameras. In order to achieve this, I first extracted the SIFT features of both of the images and matched them.

I now have **fundamental matrix** as well as **homography matrix**. However unable to proceed further, lots of confusion. Can anybody help me to **estimate the rotation and translation** in between two cameras?

I'm using OpenCV for feature extraction and matching, homography calculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the Homography then you also have the rotation. Once you have homography it is easy to get rotation and translation matrix.

For example, if you are using OpenCV c++:

```
param[in] H
param[out] pose
void cameraPoseFromHomography(const Mat& H, Mat& pose)
{
    pose = Mat::eye(3, 4, CV_32FC1);      // 3x4 matrix, the camera pose
    float norm1 = (float)norm(H.col(0));  
    float norm2 = (float)norm(H.col(1));  
    float tnorm = (norm1 + norm2) / 2.0f; // Normalization value

    Mat p1 = H.col(0);       // Pointer to first column of H
    Mat p2 = pose.col(0);    // Pointer to first column of pose (empty)

    cv::normalize(p1, p2);   // Normalize the rotation, and copies the column to pose

    p1 = H.col(1);           // Pointer to second column of H
    p2 = pose.col(1);        // Pointer to second column of pose (empty)

    cv::normalize(p1, p2);   // Normalize the rotation and copies the column to pose

    p1 = pose.col(0);
    p2 = pose.col(1);

    Mat p3 = p1.cross(p2);   // Computes the cross-product of p1 and p2
    Mat c2 = pose.col(2);    // Pointer to third column of pose
    p3.copyTo(c2);       // Third column is the crossproduct of columns one and two

    pose.col(3) = H.col(2) / tnorm;  //vector t [R|t] is the last column of pose
}
```

This function calculates de camera pose from homography, in which rotation is contained. For further theoretical info follow this [thread](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/2737/1473).

Comment: Thank you @Jav_Rock, your answer helped me to estimate pose. However for any image sets pose matrix is coming same, first three columns form a identity matrix and last column is empty. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I also confirmed the homography matrix by using warpAffine, its correctly mapping the view of an image on to another.

Comment: @user1709317: `H` and `pose` need to be of the same format. You will probably get the desired results if you change `CV_32FC1`-> `CV_64FC1`.