# Finding displacement between two camera frames

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography, pose-estimation

I'm currently working on a visual odometry project. Currently I've implemented up to Essential Matrix decomposition stage. But the resulting translation vector is normalized and cannot be able to plot the movement.

Now how can I compute the displacement in some scale? I have seen some suggestions to use planner homography to compute the absolute translation. I didn't got the idea of doing it as, the outdoor environment is not simply planner. At least, by considering the ground as planner, how to obtain, the translation of it. I've seen a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658839/multiple-view-geometry/12660869#12660869). Is it possible to use this approach to get the displacement between two frames?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called registration. This is a vast field. There are methods for linear transformation across the entire image, and per pixel methods ( the two ends of the spectrum). Naturally per pixel methods are far slower typically and have many local errors.

Typically two frames have very little transformation between them and simple Homography will do to find the general scaling between them. Especially if you are talking about aerial photos. If your case is very far from planar then you may want to use something closer to pixel-wise. For example using spline fitting: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20057-b-spline-grid--image-and-point-based-registration

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recover scale, generally speaking, unless you can recognize in the scene 1 or more objects of known physical size.